# Recove data from xml file with ruby for manipulating

Tags: ruby, xml

i have a problem. I must recover the data from a xml file inside my print machine becouse i want recove number of copy each day but i can see only total copy from start day of machine.
My script must recover from xml file the total copy day by day and with my manipulition the script subtracts the number each day.
I have alredy try use my little script like follow

```
require 'net/http' 
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse( "http://192.168.1.80/wcd/system_counter.xml" )
params = {'q'=>'cheese'}

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port) 
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path) 
request.set_form_data( params )

# instantiate a new Request object
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new( uri.path+ '?' + request.body ) 

response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```

but when i try with other html page i have correctly response and i can see the code of page with my page i have this html page like response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<meta content="text/javascript" http-equiv="Content-Script-Type">
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/wcd/js_error.xml">
</noscript>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#ffffff" LINK="#000000" ALINK="#ff0000" VLINK="#000000" onload="location.replace('/wcd/index.html?access=SYS_COU');" >
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

When i go from browser i can see correctly number of copy.

What for your experiece the correctly mode for bypass this restriction with ruby code?

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Declaring multiple variables on the same line by slamming the code together with `;` is a bad habit to get into. Keep them on separate lines for consistency.

Comment: really in the post not indent correctly and i was forced to write in the same line.

Comment: It appears to be using a frameset which can be a nightmare to try and parse. additionally that frameset appears to be using a javascript redirect (which you cannot follow without a js capable web driver). have your tried accessing the page it is trying to redirect you to "/wcd/index.html?access=SYS_COU" directly instead? Also on a sidenote I am not sure what your comment means but I editted your post to avoid the single line issue

Comment: @engineersmnky i not know what is that page. Have you an idea how i can check. Thanks. Thanks for your intervention

Comment: "http://192.168.1.80/wcd/index.html?access=SYS_COU" try visiting that page?

Comment: it's return on browser to index page at http://192.168.1.80/wcd/system_device.xml how i can see the info about machine